# How different is this to creating a primary key on a column in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I read that we cannot create a primary key on a column in a Hive table. But I saw the below DDL in some other place and executed it. It worked without any problem.

```
create table prim(id int, name char(30))
TBLPROPERTIES("PRIMARY KEY"="id");
```

After this I executed "describe formatted prim" and got to see that a key is created on the column ID

```
Table Parameters:        
PRIMARY KEY             id
```

I inserted two records with same ID number into the table.

```
insert into prim values(1,'ABCD');
insert into prim values(2,'EFGH');
```

Both the records were inserted into the table. What baffles me is that we cannot give the PRIMARY KEY in the create statement which I can understand, but when given in `TBLPROPERTIES("PRIMARY KEY"="id")` how different is it to the primary key in RDBMS.

Comment: I believe hive support non-validated primary and foreign key constraints. You can look into the doc for the same.

Answer (score 3):

`PRIMARY KEY` in `TBLPROPERTIES` is for metadata reference to preserve column significance. It does not apply any constrain on that column.  This can be used as a reference from design perspective.

Comment: could you explain this bit: "metadata reference to preserve column significance".

Comment: For the case when table is replicated on the line of RDBMS table then maintaining the details of the constrain in bigdata will help in future design. Might be in future ACID implemenation of hive will make use of this.

Comment: This will also help developer to write hive query on the table as it give the insight on how the data is distributed.